# The cursor of pymysql fail to exercute SQL language

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pycharm

I would like to use pymysql to update the data in mysql database. But I don't know what's going wrong with my code. 
IDE： pycharm

```
name1=input("enter the new one")
stu_ID=int(input("enter student ID"))
sql=f."UPDATE student SET name={name1} WHERE ID={stu_ID}"
cursor. execute(sql)
```

Comment: What is "f"? what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since in your post is missing the error, i'm going to suppose that code is working fine but data are not updated at the end of the execution. If this assumption is not true, please add the error.

In your code is not present the declaration of database connection and from my point of viewm the problem could be there. In fact, for the update statement you should add parameter *autocommit=True*.

Check the following example:

```
database_connection=pymysql.connect(host=my_host, 
                                   user=my_user, 
                                   password=my_psw, 
                                   db=my_db_name, 
                                   charset=my_db_charset, 
                                   cursorclass=my_cursor_type, 
                                   autocommit=True)
```

This because pymysql starts an implicit transaction in case of update. 
So in your case (without autocommit), at the end of the query execution, data are rollbacked.

Another different option, if you don't want add the autocommit in the database connection declaration is add an esplicit commit after the query like this:

```
database_connection.commit()
```